# Magmi - Magento Mass Import - How to Import Image as Base Image, Thumbnail & Small Image?

Tags: magento-1.7, import, magmi

I am new to Magmi and am wondering if anyone has figured out how to correctly import an image so it automatically is set to base image, thumbnail and small image?

I currently can import images but it is only set as the base image.

Their documentation for itemprocessor "Image attributes processor v1.0.24" is [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor) but I do not really understand how to get my result.

Comment: Raphael Rafatpanah I have the same problem ... but is not working even after I created thoese 2 columns. Do you have any ideea ... WHY ? Actually, there are 2 main issues: after import, I must enter in Admin to sellect catergory and to click on Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail... is not such confortable for hundereds items :) I wait your kind reply if you know how to fix thoese 2 issues. CHeers

Comment: @NikosZeolini, are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the answer is simple.

You have to add these fields on the .csv file:

```
thumbnail

small_image
```

Then, add the image names in the proper fields and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

@ Nikos Zeolini It sounds like the problem you're having is enabling the base image so that it's visible and clickable in the media gallery. I had the same problem.

By default all base images are excluded from the gallery so we need to add a "+" before all images in the main "image" column before running the import with MagMI.

e.g. 
image,small_image,thumbnail,media_gallery

+/1A-1.jpg,/1A-1.jpg,/1A-1.jpg,/1A-1.jpg; /1A-2.jpg; /1A-3.jpg

+/EX-1.jpg,/EX-1.jpg,/EX-1.jpg,/EX-1.jpg; /EX-2.jpg; /EX-3.jpg

Hope this helps!