# Magento product import using magmi Base Image, Small image and Thumbnail fields not selected

Tags: magmi, magento-community, magento-1.9.3.3, import-products

I have imported products, categories and images successfully using Magmi but Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail attributes of the image are not getting selected.

[image]

Comment: try this link once  : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor   , also https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88892/magmi-base-image-include-in-gallery-being-ignored   and  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/magmi-magento-mass-import-how-to-import-image-as-base-image-thumbnail-sma

Comment: all links checked. nothing works!

Comment: some sample  you will get online for magmi, try with those once......

Comment: Oops.. My mistake. Base images were not uploaded and that's the reason why it was not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credits : OP : **Brijesh Kapletiya**

As per discussion in comments, Base images were not uploaded so Images were not selected....